# Where can I find the QTC_SOURCE files for Qt Creator plugins

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am referring to the files I need to point to in QTC_SOURCE variable.

I don't have admin access so I can't install the -dev packages as many pages suggest. I would prefer files I can directly download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the Qt Creator source code. Download a tarball (.tar.gz or .zip) from [here](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qtcreator/) or clone the [git repository](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-creator/qt-creator.git).